# Update dirty records in MongoDb

Tags: mongodb

I have one document with some dirty records like this:

```
document-> {       
    "_id" : "123",
    "dirty_to_clean" : [
            "5ddc36f5e9c5cd64b437b466",
            "5ddc14b4e9c5cd64b437b2be",
            [
                "5dd6d8d6e9c5cd64b437a127",
                "5dd6a9bce9c5cd64b4379ef3",
                "5dd5a594e9c5cd64b43799a9"
            ]
        ]
}
```

and I need to fix/update it, so it stays like this:

```
document -> {       
    "_id" : "123",
    "dirty_to_clean" : [
            "5ddc36f5e9c5cd64b437b466",
            "5ddc14b4e9c5cd64b437b2be",
            "5dd6d8d6e9c5cd64b437a127",
            "5dd6a9bce9c5cd64b4379ef3",
            "5dd5a594e9c5cd64b43799a9"              
        ]
}
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an aggregation pipeline to reshape the data and then the `$out` operator to overwrite the collection with it. You can achieve it with the following code:

```
  db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$dirty_to_clean",
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$dirty_to_clean",
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      "dirty_to_clean": {
        $push: "$dirty_to_clean"
      }
    },
  },
  {
    $out: {
      db: "<output-db>",
      coll: "<output-collection>"
    }
  }
]);
```

The first `$unwind` splits the first level into one document copy per item. So considering your document has this structure:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "123",
    "dirty_to_clean": [
      "5ddc36f5e9c5cd64b437b466",
      "5ddc14b4e9c5cd64b437b2be",
      [
        "5dd6d8d6e9c5cd64b437a127",
        "5dd6a9bce9c5cd64b4379ef3",
        "5dd5a594e9c5cd64b43799a9"
      ]
    ]
  }
]
```

After the first `$unwind` you will get this:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "123",
    "dirty_to_clean": "5ddc36f5e9c5cd64b437b466"
  },
  {
    "_id": "123",
    "dirty_to_clean": "5ddc14b4e9c5cd64b437b2be"
  },
  {
    "_id": "123",
    "dirty_to_clean": [
      "5dd6d8d6e9c5cd64b437a127",
      "5dd6a9bce9c5cd64b4379ef3",
      "5dd5a594e9c5cd64b43799a9"
    ]
  }
]
```

The second `$unwind` will split the nested arrays, leaving you with:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "123",
    "dirty_to_clean": "5ddc36f5e9c5cd64b437b466"
  },
  {
    "_id": "123",
    "dirty_to_clean": "5ddc14b4e9c5cd64b437b2be"
  },
  {
    "_id": "123",
    "dirty_to_clean": "5dd6d8d6e9c5cd64b437a127"
  },
  {
    "_id": "123",
    "dirty_to_clean": "5dd6a9bce9c5cd64b4379ef3"
  },
  {
    "_id": "123",
    "dirty_to_clean": "5dd5a594e9c5cd64b43799a9"
  }
]
```

Then you can use `$group` by the `_id` and push every `dirty_to_clean` value to an array called **dirty_to_clean** to have your final clean structure:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "123",
    "dirty_to_clean": [
      "5ddc36f5e9c5cd64b437b466",
      "5ddc14b4e9c5cd64b437b2be",
      "5dd6d8d6e9c5cd64b437a127",
      "5dd6a9bce9c5cd64b4379ef3",
      "5dd5a594e9c5cd64b43799a9"
    ]
  }
]
```

The `$out` pipeline stage writes the result to a collection. If you give the same name as the collection you are querying it will overwrite the data with the aggregation output.

You can see a workin example here:
https://mongoplayground.net/p/FSAnABoR1OK